# grunt-modernizr not ouputting fule

Tags: gruntjs, modernizr, yarnpkg

I installed modernizr via Yarn and am wanting to build a lean file using only the aspects of modernizr that are actually needed. To do that, I'm attempting to use grunt-modernizr (https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr), but the grunt task is not actually outputting a file.

Here is my grunt config:

```
  modernizr: {
    dist: {
      devFile: false,
      outputFile: './public/lib/js/custom-modernizr.js',
      files: {
        src: [
          './public/lib/js/main.min.js',
          './public/lib/js/vendor.min.js',
          './public/lib/css/main.min.css',
          './public/lib/css/basics-of-ed.min.css',
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

In looking at the command line, it appears that things are working properly but the file is not actually outputting (screenshot below). What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Rename the `outPutFile` property to [`dest`](https://github.com/modernizr/customizr#dest-string-optional). E.g. `dest: './public/lib/js/custom-modernizr.js',`

Comment: That was it! Thank you!